# Multiply field by value in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I've been looking for a way to create an update statement that will take an existing numeric field and modify it using an expression. For example, if I have a field called Price, is it possible to do an update that sets Price to 50% off the existing value ?

So, given `{ Price : 19.99 }`

I'd like to do `db.collection.update({tag : "refurb"}, {$set {Price : Price * 0.50 }}, false, true);`

Can this be done or do I have to read the value back to the client, modify, then update ? I guess the question then is can expressions be used in update, and can they reference the document being updated.

Comment: Please note that in an upcoming version of mongo, you can do this without all this eval and DB locking almost at no cost. Check and may be accept the new answer, so that new devs would not use obsolete info.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can run server-side code with `db.eval()`.

```
db.eval(function() { 
    db.collection.find({tag : "refurb"}).forEach(function(e) {
        e.Price = e.Price * 0.5;
        db.collection.save(e);
    });
});
```

Note this will block the DB, so it's better to do find-update operation pair.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/server-side-javascript/

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying I should use eval() like you've shown, or should do it client side with find/update to avoid blocking ?

Comment: @Brad you should evaluate the overall cost of this particular update operation. If the operation is going to be long (many docs in the collections will be updated) you should never use eval. There's no big overhead to first query a document and then update it instead of in-place update. Especially if you limit fields queried for big documents and use covered index feature (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-CoveredIndexes)

Comment: Cool, thanks. I see also eval() doesn't work with sharding, so that rules it out for me anyway long term. Nolock is an interesting addition.

Comment: This isn't atomic. See Salvador's answer using `$mul` for an atomic solution.

Answer (score 23):

In the new **Mongo 2.6.x** there is a [$mul operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/). It would multiply the value of the field by the number with the following syntax.

```
{
  $mul: { field: <number> }
}
```

So in your case you will need to do the following:

```
db.collection.update(
  { tag : "refurb"},
  { $mul: { Price : 0.5 } }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update of a field based on another field:

```
// { price: 19.99 }
// { price: 2.04  }
db.collection.update(
  {},
  [{ $set: { price: { $multiply: [ 0.5, "$price" ] } } }],
  { multi: true }
)
// { price: 9.995 }
// { price: 1.02  }
```

- The first part `{}` is the match query, filtering which documents to update (all documents in this case).
- The second part `[{ $set: { price: ... } }]` is the update aggregation pipeline (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline). [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator and an alias of `$addFields`. Note how `price` is modified directly based on the its own value (`$price`).
- Don't forget `{ multi: true }`, otherwise only the first matching document will be updated.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is possible with an atomic operation as $set.

You have several options :

- use the eval() solution proposed by pingw33n
- retrieve the document you want to modify to get the current value and modify it with a set
- if you have a high operation rate, you might want to be sure the focument has not changed during you fetch its value (using the previous solution) so you might want to use a findAndModify (see [this page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/two-phase+commit) to get inspired on how to do it) operation.

It really depends on your context : with a very low pressure on the db, I'd go for the solution of pingw33n. With a very high operation rate, I'd use the third solution.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see how findAndModify would allow using an expression though, which was my main goal.

Comment: @Brad findAndModify does allow to use expression but it allows to make a two phase action : first fetch the item and then update it (with your 50% reduction) only if it has not changed since retrieved