# MongoDB how to do this where clause update

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named 'Foo'. I'd like to update every document in the Foo collection that has a `bar` value of 100 to 1000. What's the best way to run this update in MongoDB to get an efficient update?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible with a single update statement. You can use another method as in this post: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342725/how-to-update-a-field-in-mongodb-using-existing-value

Comment: I don't think that's correct; see the response below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How to update multiple documents with a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740023/mongodb-how-to-update-multiple-documents-with-a-single-command)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_set) operator to do that:

```
db.foo.update({bar: 100}, {$set: {bar: 1000}}, false, true)
```

The fourth parameter sets the `multi` option to true so that you update all matching documents, not just the first one.

**3.2 UPDATE**

Recent MongoDB versions provide an [`updateMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) method that is a bit more intuitive:

```
db.foo.updateMany({bar: 100}, {$set: {bar: 1000}})
```