# MongoDB: Adding a new field based on an existing field using $substr

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple collection like below

```
> db.test.save({first:"Ab"})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518a1524f635dc8bb092e1ac"), "first" : "Ab" }
```

I want to add a new field called 'fl' which holds the first letter of the field "first".
I tried this

```
> db.test.update({},{"$set":{"fl":{"$substr":["$first",0,1]}}})
not okForStorage
```

But I get the exception "not okForStorage" as you can see.
Any suggestions, workarounds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update a field in MongoDB using existing value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342725/how-to-update-a-field-in-mongodb-using-existing-value)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate of [Multiply field by value in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342725/how-to-update-a-field-in-mongodb-using-existing-value) but here's a workaround:

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(e) {
  e.fi = e.first[0];
  db.save(e);
});
```