# Mongo, how to multiply field value by value

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
{
price = 140.23563
}
```

How can multiply the price by 100?

Comment: We have $inc operator in mongo, but is there operator like $multiply ?

Comment: see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/multiply/

Comment: There's no atomic operator for this.  You have to read the doc, perform the multiplication and then update the doc with the result.

Comment: @AlexandrKondaurov You should add your first comment to the question itself.  Wether you want to just multiply by 100 or do it atomically makes a big difference.  If you add more information the answers you get will be more precise.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342725/how-to-update-a-field-in-mongodb-using-existing-value

Answer (score 3):

As of the [release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#mul-update-operator) from upcoming `Mongo 2.6` you would be able to use the new $mul operator. It would multiply the value of the field by the number with the following syntax.

```
{
  field: { $mul: <number> }
}
```

P.S. keep in mind that `2.6` is not released right now, but will be really soon. You can use experimental `2.5.x` instead right now.