# Pick content from DB while using update query in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to update all the database :-

Their are Models like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593800da81dd4240d42f0c98"),
    "leaveType" : ObjectId("5927da8b7094b726fecaa3b5"),
    "units" : 20,
    "employee" : ObjectId("59283f772c3bd82eaca28153"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

What I want is, update all the models with inserting new value as `unitsAvailed` with making same Number as Corresponding units

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593800da81dd4240d42f0c98"),
    "leaveType" : ObjectId("5927da8b7094b726fecaa3b5"),
    "units" : 20,
    "unitsAvailed" : 20,
    "employee" : ObjectId("59283f772c3bd82eaca28153"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query to update all documents

```
var cursor = db.collectionName.find({});
cursor.forEach(function(data) {
  data.unitsAvailed = data.units;
  data.save();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run server-side code with db.eval().see below example

```
 db.eval(function() { 
  db.collection.find({tag : "refurb"}).forEach(function(e) {
    e.Price = e.Price * 0.5;
    db.collection.save(e);
  });
});
```

see [Multiply field by value in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342725/multiply-field-by-value-in-mongodb/8343147#8343147)

Comment: i want to make query direct on mongo shell . will this work at that place

Comment: @hardy if you are authorized you an do it on mongo shell.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
 db.collectionName.updateMany({},{$set:{unitsAvailed: 20}})
```